# Trying to open code for a control/form brings up Form Designer code

Tags: vb.net, forms

I used to program in VB6 professionally (up to about 6 years ago).  Now I'm trying to write a personal program in Visual Studio 2017 Community.  I'm having a problem:

I had the program finished but needed to embed an ICO file in the EXE and couldn't get it to work.  Somewhere in the process, I screwed something up.  None of my "code-behind" stuff is running.  That is, form_load doesn't run, none of the code associated with the buttons runs when clicked upon, nothing.  Double-clicking a button to see the code behind it actually brings up the Form1.Designer.vb window (which I'd not seen before).

It's as if all the code behind the form has been orphaned and the form and the code which had been associated with it have been separated.  I'm sure I did something stupid while monkeying with settings to try to get the ICO file to embed but I have no clue what I did wrong.

Suggestions?  Please.  :-/

--HC

Comment: If nothing else, hopefully this demonstrates why keeping backups of a project is a good idea. Even for a lone developer, using source code control is a good idea as it can help you recover from situations like this.

Comment: It's almost impossible for us to say what you did wrong without seeing the code.  Maybe you copied/moved the code from the user code file into the designer code file. Click the `Show All Files` button in the Solution Explorer and open both code files.  Do they look as you would expect?  Compare them to another working project and see the type of code in each.  The designer file shoudn't have much more than declarations and the `InitializeComponent` method, while all control event handlers should be in the user file.

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  I am having some difficulty coming from the old VB6 world.  You're right, it does point out the value of source control.  I looked over the files as you suggested and they seem to be different in the tree-view.  I think, as I got carried away trying to add a resource file, I dragged and/or deleted a file in the tree-view.  I managed to copy the code and the form controls to a new project and got it going.  I will be more careful in the future.  Thanks again.